# full screen google map with swipe menu

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fullscreen, swipe

I am trying to create a full screen google map web app with jquery panel menus showing up on swipe event. But map is not visible at all, it's like totally omitted or obscured.I couldn't figure out why.... Could you pls let me know where I am doing wrong in below code?

I followed jquery demo version as presented in their official website for the code, but still doesn't work.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/mobile/code/js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/mobile/code/js/javaModule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE"></script>

        <style>
    #index,#GMAP {
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       padding:0;
    }</style>

    <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="index">

                <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="GMAP">
                </div>

                <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">
                <p>Left Reveal Panel</p>
                <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-right">Close</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="b">
                <p>Right push panel.</p>
                <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Close</a>
                </div>

      </div>



<script>
   $(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function () {
          $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#index", function( e ) {
            
            if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                    $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                    $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                }
            }
        });
    });

     $(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function (){

         var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: {lat:38.6075, lng:27.0694},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("GMAP"), myOptions);

         });

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi cenk, did you get any solution? because I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE"></script>` where it say MY_KEY_HERE you must remplace for a real one.

Comment: Of course I did it..For the sake of confidentiality I replaced the My_key_Here string.

Comment: The problem is when I omit left-panel and right-panel divs, and omit related $(document) handling code, everything works fine...full screen map is shown...but I want to embed a menu panel when swiping from left or right.